# VBScript Readline method ignoring 3rd IF statement

Tags: vbscript, readline

My script doesn't seem to check the "secLine" again for the 3rd if statement.  It should remember what's stored in "secLine"....hmmmm

This is the text:

```
PHL DEPARTURES OVER  TUSKY  PLEASE FILE:
PHL..DITCH.V312.JIMEE..WAVEY..SHLEP..ACK..DIRECT
```

SCRIPT:

```
If InStr(firLine, "PHL DEPARTURES OVER  TUSKY  PLEASE") Then
    secLine = objFile.ReadLine
If InStr(secLine, "JFK..PUT..BOS..DIRECT") or InStr(secLine, "PHL..DITCH.J225.JFK..PUT..BOS..DIRECT") Then  
    trans507="TUSKY"
    ind507="1"

    bunch of code

If Instr(secLine, "WAVEY..SHLEP..ACK..DIRECT") Then
    ind507="2"

    bunch of code

End If
End If
End If
```

Comment: your current edit (3 trailing End Ifs) won't do what you want; if you indent correctly, you'll see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the first IF succeeds (right now your published data don't match the literal).

Don't use the shortened version(s) of the IF statement. Always use

```
If ... Then
   ...
End If
```

Make sure your indentation truly reflects the script's structure.

In code:

```
If InStr(firLine, "PHL DEPARTURES OVER TUSKY PLEASE") Then
    secLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(secLine, "JFK..PUT..BOS..DIRECT") or InStr(secLine, "PHL..DITCH.J225.JFK..PUT..BOS..DIRECT") Then
       trans507="TUSKY"
       ind507="1"
    End If
    If Instr(secLine, "WAVEY..SHLEP..ACK..DIRECT") Then
       ind507="2"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was a stupidly obvious mistake my part....
So the solution was that I couldn't put all the "End If" statements at the bottom, I needed to "End If" the first If InStr(secLine ... 

Thanks again.